# How to correct the width of a div in css

Tags: html, css, footer

So I'm currently screwing around with website design in HTML and CSS and I've faced a kinda weird problem. I've got a footer I want to put at the bottom of the screen, but when I do that the width of it is smaller that I want it, that being the width of the window. If i set the width to 100%, it makes the width wider than the screen and gives me that little scrollbar at the bottom at the screen. I have a main like wrapper thing and inside it I have my footer. Here's the CSS:

```
.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

this code currently sticks the footer to the bottom of the screen, but makes it too small. I have like no idea how to fix this, and if there is a way it'd be nice to know.

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    
    <!-- other stuff here -->

    <div class="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to look at the full HTML structure, and not just the CSS. I also wonder why you don't use `display: sticky` or `display: fixed`.

Comment: oh ok. the reason i dont use stuff like that is because i didnt know that existed so um imma try that out

Comment: try width:100vw

Comment: Do you know anything about box-sizing?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: You probably have a margin or padding in your body or HTML element. Use the `html, body` selector and set the margin and padding to `0px`.

Comment: @BenZ. Ive got that in the css and its not helping

Comment: Neither of the answers have helped for some reason. Maybe its something wrong with the browser but I tried both firefox and chrome and it still hasnt worked

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to achieve what you're attempting. Below I set a `fixed` position on your footer and set the main-wrapper and footer to `100vw`.

```css
.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <!-- other stuff here -->

  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, here is another option using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

In the example below, the `body` container is set to the height of the window, and the `main-wrapper` div is told to expand as needed.

This is a better option because it is automatically mobile responsive and won't break if the height of the footer changes.

**Note:** I have adjusted your HTML in this example and moved the footer div outside of the main-wrapper.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">

  <!-- other stuff here -->

</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason this still doesnt work ive tried both methods

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex or grid to keep all element in the flow and then set a scrollbar on the screen or what stands before the footer:

grid examples:

footer at bottom but can be pushed down

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

main {
  background: hotpink;
}

footer {
  background: gray;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  All of my stuff here
</main>
<footer>My bottom footer</footer>
```

grid with main scrolling

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

main {
  background: hotpink;
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  background: gray;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br>  All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br>  All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br> All of my stuff here<br>
</main>
<footer>My bottom footer</footer>
```

if you need a flex example, ask with a comment below.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. Turns out that using position: fixed or position: sticky will fix it